# MySQL Get products also bought with a product / Optimise IN query

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart, query-optimization

I'm trying to write a simple 'customers who bought this also bought...'

I have an `order` table, which contains orders, and an `order_product` table which contains all the products relating to an order.

In an attempt to find out the five most popular products that were bought with `product_id = 155` I've composed the following query:

```
select product_id, count(*) as cnt 
from order_product 
where product_id != 155 
and order_id in 
(select order_id from order_product where product_id = 155) 
group by product_id 
order by cnt desc 
limit 5;
```

So the inner query gets a list of all the orders that have the product I'm interested in (product_id = 155) then the outer query looks for all the products that aren't the same product but are in the one of the order that my product is in.

They are then ordered and limited to the top 5.

I think this works ok but it takes ages - I imagine this is because I'm using IN with a list of a couple of thousand.

I wonder if anyone could point me in the direction of writing it in a more optimised way.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you ever have the same `product_id` in an "order" twice?  If so, the answer has to work harder.

Comment: Good point, but no - if a product of the same `id` is added to an order then the `qty` field should be incremented rather than another record added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing this:

```
select p1.product_id, p1.count(*) as cnt
```

To

```
select p1.product_id, count(distinct p1.order_id) as cnt
```

And see if that gives you any different result

Edit:
From the comments

If you prefer having the result you generate in your first query, you can try using this:

```
select a.product_id, count(*) as cnt 
from order_product a
join (select distinct order_id from order_product where product_id = 155) b on (a.order_id = b.order_id)
where a.product_id != 155 
group by a.product_id 
order by cnt desc 
limit 5;
```

A small alteration to your existing query :)

Comment: Yeah that does give a different result. In fact all 3 are different,

Comment: By doing some testing, it seems that in your case count(*) gives how many of a given product_id has been ordered along side of product 155. While count(distinct p1.order_id) gives you the number of orders a given product_id has had along side of product 155. If that made any sense?

Comment: yeah, i think that does make sense, however, i would have expected one of them (the 1st i think) to give the same results as my original query but neither do!?

Comment: I might have been a bit wrong in my previous statement. After a bit more research, from what I understand. Your first query: counts all products associated with 155 regardless if its the same order or not (say product 111 was ordered three times in order 1 alongside 155, your query counts this as three). The count(*) takes all products associated with 155 as well as any duplicates caused by the join, and the count(distinct order_id) counts the unique number of orders said product has been in with 155.

Comment: Let me know if the query still takes ages :)

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense (i think). Your new query answer does indeed give the same result as my original and does it way faster.

Comment: Apologies, explaining things that I see clearly in my head ain't my strongest trait. My point was that its explainable why the results vary. :) The performance differences are probably as you already pointed out, the 'IN' with select does tend to fall behind a bit on large amount of data, while join on said amount of data are much faster (even faster with indexed ID's)

Comment: No, you explained it just fine - the (i think) was more a reference to my dimwittedness than your powers of explanation... many thanks for all your help..

Comment: Hehe, you live, you learn (I like to say), you are very welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a Join instead a subselect. Something like:

```
select p1.product_id, p1.count(*) as cnt 
from order_product p1 JOIN order_product p2 on p1.order_id = p2. order_id
where p1.product_id != 155 
and p2.product_id = 155
group by p1.product_id 
order by p1.cnt desc 
limit 5;
```

Comment: using count(*) without the prefix works but gives different results to my original query

Comment: Manually check the two queries -- which one has the correct counts?

Comment: And if you want the product 'namex', then do `SELECT name FROM ( Diego's query ) AS x JOIN products USING(product_id)`.